# Passing a SimpleXMLElement as a provider in PHPUnit

Tags: php, phpunit, simplexml

I am attempting to craft some unit tests with PHPUnit to test the handling of XML responses from AWS by some message handler classes I am experimenting with.  I thought I'd try loading the XML file I have saved into a file into an XML object and then passing this into the tests would be a neat way to do things so I attempted the following:

```
class cs_responses_tests extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    public static function DescribeDomainResults_Provider(){
        $xml = simplexml_load_file(__DIR__ .'/DescribeDomainsResult.xml');

        return [$xml];
    }

    /**
     * @dataProvider DescribeDomainResults_Provider
     */

    public function test_DomainStatus_ClassBasic($xml){
        $obj = new DomainStatus($xml);

        assertInstanceOf('DomainStatus', $obj);
    }
}
```

However this generates an `Data set #0 is invalid.` warning.  I have tried putting `var_dump($xml)` right after the `simplexml_load_file` and the XML is being loaded correctly.

The fact it says data set #0, leads me to believe that the array is passing correctly (as the xml object should be element 0), I have tried making the provider non-static and static but this seems to make no difference.

Am I missing something? or is it not possible to pass object instances from providers within PHPUnit?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should return something like this `return [[$xml]];` there needs to be one array for data sets and second one for parameters.

Comment: Thanks that works!  Looking back at my other tests with scalar values I can see this now! doh! thanks, I must need sleep :)